WhatsApp business number-register : call to /v21/<phone_number_id>/register fails
I have been trying to register my facebook whatsapp business account but it is not working. Am I using the correct api? Or what am I doing wrong?
Note: I have passed the correct phone number id and a valid bearer token. This is the response i get. How can I resolve this issue? Has the endpoint changed?

